# How to triple boot computer: backtrack 5r3, win7 and ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, backtrack, wubi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to triple boot xp, backtrack and 7](https://superuser.com/questions/93020/how-to-triple-boot-xp-backtrack-and-7)

I want my computer to be triple booted: Backtrack 5r3, Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7. It doesn't matter which will be the first to be installed, because it is going to be on a new computer. For windows I know that there's wubi installer to dual boot it to ubuntu, but what about backtrack. I think it'll be something like this:

Windows - 300GB

Ubuntu - 150GB

Backtrack - 50GB

Please give full instructions, because I am a noob in booting and especially triple booting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to triple boot xp, backtrack and 7](http://superuser.com/questions/93020/how-to-triple-boot-xp-backtrack-and-7) also see [How to install Ubuntu, Windows XP and Windows 7 from scratch as triple-boot system](http://superuser.com/questions/41595/how-to-install-ubuntu-windows-xp-and-windows-7-from-scratch-as-triple-boot-syst)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you know how to boot from USB/CD etc and have all the installation software you need?

First, install Windows. Don't worry too much about drivers/service packs etc. Once you get the first welcome screen, Shut down.

Secondly install BT5.3 - During install you will get the option to Install backtrack/ubuntu alongside windows 7. Make sure you select this. Install Backtrack up until main login.

When you restart your computer you will be given the options of Windows and two ubuntu options - You will need to remember what one is what, or look into GRUB2 menu editing so you can rename the options at login.

Thirdly, install Ubuntu. The same option during install will appear for installation of Ubuntu / Windows - It will either create it's own partition or install within backtrack partition - I can't remember exactly.

I personally would install Just Windows and Ubuntu, and keep BT on a USB stick - Runs very well that way and can be set to remember who you are and save your settings as you use it.

There can be lots of issues that may crop up but if you let me know here I will do my best to answer them. Make sure the computer you are installing to has nothing important on it. Things can and do go wrong during these processes.

Comment: Ok, so the option to install BT alongside windows will be in the BackTrack installation program? And I didn't quite understand this: "When you restart your computer you will be given the options of Windows and two ubuntu options - You will need to remember what one is what, or look into GRUB2 menu editing so you can rename the options at login." This means that it will give me the option to boot into Backtrack or Windows? And what is GRUB2? So every install will give me the option to create it's own partition yes, but how to specify the size - I don't want backtrack to have 400GB

Comment: Yes - you are given the option to install Windows alongside Backtrack/Ubuntu. You can also drag a slider bar to choose how much disk space you wish to assign to which OS. The grub2 menu is installed with most modern linux distributions. This is what you would use to select which OS you want to use when the computer starts up.

Comment: So I don't understand what grub is yet, but I have another 2 questions: What if instead of win7 there'll be win8? Can I install ubuntu with wubi or DVD or it doesn't matter?

Comment: You don't need to know what grub does apart from one thing - It allows you to choose what you want to use at startup - either ubuntu or win7. Always use DVD to install.

Comment: but there will be backtrack too and at every startup i will need to choose what I want yes?

Comment: Yes - You get a menu to choose what OS

Comment: OK, like a simple boot menu, so the most important thing is to create a separate partition for every OS

Answer (score 0):

I does not depend on what OSes you use, any dual/triple-boot guide will work for you. If you computer has [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS) I recommend [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) as OS chooser. If your computer has EFI/[UEFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) try [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/).

I recommend you install the OSes using these hard disk capacities in this order: Windows, Backtrack and Linux. Install boot loader of each one in their partition and GRUB/rEFInd in the hard disk MBR at the end with Ubuntu installer.